# How to add a prefix to a big list?

Tags: linux, sed, cygwin, prefix

I want to add a prefix to each line found in line.txt.
Example:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Output should be:

```
--line1
--line2
--line3
```

I am using cygwin to do linux command in cmd:

```
sed -e 's/^/--/' line.txt > output.txt
```

but I get this error:

```
sed -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

The file is too big to open with excel, so I need a way to do it from cmd.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it does not work with Cygwin, but I installed a Linux on a Virtualbox, and it worked with the original command:

```
sed -e 's/^/--/' line.txt > output.txt
```

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer you are looking for:

```
sed 's/^.*$/--&/g' line.txt
```

The key point here is that `&` represents the element that was identified in the first part of the regex (i.e., Whatever is before the forward slash is repeated with the ampersand `&`)

Testing - inserting characters after and before the original strings:

```
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ touch test.txt
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ echo "line1" >> test.txt
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ echo "line2" >> test.txt
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ echo "line3" >> test.txt
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ sed 's/^.*$/&@email.com/g' test.txt
line1@email.com
line2@email.com
line3@email.com
[themarcelor@linuxbox tmp]$ sed 's/^.*$/--&/g' test.txt
--line1
--line2
--line3
```

Comment: Hey.

It just says:

sed -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated 's' command

The following name </g'> the system cant recognize.

Comment: I think the issue might be that I am not running a linux, but cygwin.

Comment: hmm, probably it's because you are running these commands on cygwin :( try to remove the /g and see what happens. You can also try your original command but, this time, use /.*/--&/

Comment: If I do:
sed 's/^.*$/--&' line.txt
It gives same error but with <'>, if I remove that too and do this: sed 's/^.*$/--& line.txt it just opens the line.txt and does nothing. With this it gives same error:/.*/--&/ as the first time

Comment: `g` is not needed here becasue it change the whole line at once so no other occurence on the same line can occur

Comment: @Simon : Dude, get one of those Ubuntu Live CDs :)